# Getting the second highest and second lowest java

Tags: java, sorting

Getting the second highest and second lowest java without using array array sort or any sorting method, min_value and max_value just for loop and if statement I already started to code this is what ive done so far i cant think of how can i get the second lowest and second highest

```
package Lab2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class hehe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int fh, sh, fl, sl, x;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 5 numbers: ");
        x = fh = sh = sl = fl = s.nextInt();
        int a,b,c,d;
        int mid = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            int n = s.nextInt();
            if (fh < n) {
                fh = n;
            }
            if (fl > n) {
                fl = n;
            }
            for(int y=0;y<5;y++){

            }
        }

        System.out.println("The First highest is: " + fh);
        System.out.println("The Second highest is: " + sh);
        System.out.println("The Second lowest is: " + sl);
        System.out.println("The First lowest is: " + fl);
        System.out.println(mid);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case it is easier to put your values into array and sort it.

Comment: I cant use array haha my professor wont allow me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (fh < n) {
                         sh = fh;
                         fh = n;
                    }else if (sh < n) 
                           {
                             sh = n;
                           }
         if (fl > n) {
                         s1=f1
                         fl = n;
                    }else if (s1 > n) 
                         {
                            s1 = n;
                         }
```

Comment: It actually don't. But problem id in your  code. Try to enter 1 2 3 4 5 as input.

Comment: Ya it wont work correctly when i tried to input the 5 first and then 4 ,-2 -2 1 the output was 5 5 -2 -2

Answer (score 2):

Just improve upon your condition to cover all cases,

```
// Initialize your variables like this,
fh = sh = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
fl = sl = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

// Change your for loop condition to below and get input only inside the loop. Not before it.
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {

if (fh < n) { // It means you have received the highest known number
    sh = fh; // The existing highest becomes the second highest now
    fh = n; // n should now be the (first) highest rightfully
} else if (sh < n) { // This means n was not the highest, but second highest
    sh = n;
}

// Do the same for lowest also.
```

Comment: Thank you ill try to do it.

Comment: Bro i found some error it wont work correctly when you enter the first input as the highest value for example i inputed first the 5 then 4 , -2 -2 1 the output will be 5 5 1-2

Comment: I cant use integer.MIN_VALUE not allowed to use it in class

Comment: Then use their actual values `2147483647` for MAX_VALUE, `-2147483648` for MIN_VALUE instead.

Comment: It wont work either it print 2147483647 as the first and second highest and  negative for the second and first lowest

Comment: @Presmelito, that means you have exchanged the values. Note that fh & sh should have negative and fl & sl should have the positive at first.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, sorting the array is the obvious solution so I assume this is some sort of test assignment. Anyway, I guess the easiest way is just to have variables for both highest and 2nd highest (and same for lowest). For example, to find the 2nd highest:

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    values.add((int) (Math.random() * 10));
}

int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int second = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for(int n: values) {
    if(n > highest) {
        second = highest;
        highest = n;
    } else if(n > second) {
        second = n;
    }
}
System.out.println("2nd highest: " + second);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but i cant use array and that integer.min_value im a beginner i am not allowed to use those haha

Answer (score 0):

You need to also update the value of variable accordingly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int fh, sh, fl, sl, x;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 5 numbers: ");
        x = fh = sh = sl = fl = s.nextInt();
        int a,b,c,d;
        int mid = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            int n = s.nextInt();
            if (fh < n) {
                sh = fh; // We have got new fh so sh is old value of fh.
                fh = n;
            }
            if (fl > n) {
                sl = fl;
                fl = n;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The First highest is: " + fh);
        System.out.println("The Second highest is: " + sh);
        System.out.println("The Second lowest is: " + sl);
        System.out.println("The First lowest is: " + fl);
    }
```